# How to give styles to Fluent UI Components?

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm starting to use FluentUI with React and I'm trying to modify the Panel component.
I've got this code:

```
  const panelStyles = {
      position: "absolute",
      top:0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      margin: "auto"
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <DefaultButton text={searchText} onClick={openPanel} />
      <Panel
        headerText="Sample panel"
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onDismiss={dismissPanel}
        closeButtonAriaLabel="Cerrar"
        styles={panelStyles}
      >
        <p>Content goes here.</p>
      </Panel>
    </div>
  );
```

but the styles = {panelStyles} gives me the following error:
The expected type comes from property 'styles' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPanelProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

The default panel opens on the left and I would like it to be centered on the screen when it opens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property `styles` of `Panel` component gives you a set of properties which you can use to modify styles.

This is example how to change `backgroundColor` of *Panel Component*:

```
styles={{
   main: {
     backgroundColor: '#f00',
   },
}}
```

Panel Component:

```
<Panel
  styles={{
    main: {
      backgroundColor: '#f00',
    },
  }}
/>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/vYXXxmp).

**Useful links:**

- Definition of [Panel Component styles](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/cbc0b9a2f9b569eeabd7bba3812002edcca948e8/packages/react-internal/src/components/Panel/Panel.styles.ts#L23)
- And this one is the most important [Component Styling](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling)